# Hyperbolic Intuition.

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I am working with hyperbolic functions and was wondering where they actually came from. I am under the understanding that Ricotta (and I think Johann Heinrich Lambert also did work in this area), did major work in this area however I am wondering how he got to the final definition of sinh and cosh using the exponential function.

Did Ricotta or Lambert ever publish a research paper which I can access somehow? I really want to understand where they come from (or if someone can show me).

Another question I had was why people required finding the Taylor expansion for both sing and cosh, what is the purpose? Why is it useful?

Thank you so much,

Comment: This masters thesis with a bit of history  http://scimath.unl.edu/MIM/files/MATExamFiles/Schutz_MATpaper_FINAL.pdf can be a good starting point.

Comment: You should ask your second question separately, you'll get better answers.

Comment: I have no insight into the historical matters, but the connection to the circular functions with imaginary arguments seems obvious. $\cos ix=(e^{i^2t}+e^{-i^2t})/2=\cosh t$, $\sin it=(e^{i^2t}-e^{-i^2t})/2i=i\sinh t$, and the unit circle turns to the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$.

Comment: Ok thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather complete history in [Enter, Stage Center: The Early Drama of the Hyperbolic Functions](http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/enter-stage-center-the-early-drama-of-the-hyperbolic-functions).